# Stringify working on chrome but causing errors in electron js app

Tags: javascript, parsing, electron, stringify

I have this code sample that I'm using to call datas from an api. I had to parse it and stringify it. And it's working if I use it on standard chrome browser, but the exact samecode running under electron js app isnt working as intended.

```js
var callBackGetSuccess = function(data) {
  console.log("donnees api", data);
  var element = document.getElementById("affichage_elo");
  var last_match = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.last_match));
  element.innerHTML = "L'élo de ce joueur est " + last_match.players[0].rating;
}


function buttonClickGET() {
  var queryLoc = document.getElementById("queryLoc").value;

  var url = "https://aoe2.net/api/player/lastmatch?game=aoe2de&steam_id=76561198871769134"

  $.get(url, callBackGetSuccess).done(function() {
      //alert( "second success" );
  })
      .fail(function() {
          alert( "error" );
      })
      .always(function() {
          //alert( "finished" );
      });
}
```

I keep getting " VM221:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at Object.callBackGetSuccess [as success] (meteo.js:4)" . I don't really get why. If you have any idea it would be nice.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Some notes: don't use `innerHTML` if you want to set text. Use `textContent`. Also, don't use `alert`, it locks the JS process, and is from a different era of old JS. In current (not even modern, really) JS, use `console.log` and related functions. Also remember that `JSON.parse` can throw, so you always want to put it in a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work finally. I wasnt just using the parse function correctly. Here is how i got it to work. ( But this way it's not working on chrome anymore. Anyway it's working on my app so I don't mind. )

```js
var callBackGetSuccess = function(data,queryLoc) {
  console.log(data.last_match);
  console.log("donnees api", data);
  var element = document.getElementById("affichage_elo");
  var element2 = document.getElementById("affichage_elo2");
  var last_match = JSON.parse(data).last_match;
```

Thanks a lot for the suggestions btw, it didnt really solve my problem but gave me some good tips to developp better stuff later.